# Using BigInteger with Realm Java?

Tags: java, android, realm, biginteger

Realm Java does not support `BigInteger` so the following class:

```
public class Bonus extends RealmObject {
   String thebonus;
   BigInteger bonus;

   ...

   public BigInteger getBonus() {
    return bonus;
   }

   public void setBonus(BigInteger newBonus) {
    this.bonus = newBonus;
   }
}
```

results in **Field "value" of type "java.math.BigInteger" is not supported.**

I use the Realm like:
`bnsInitial.setBonus(new BigInteger("0"));` or something like `int x = bns.getBonus().compareTo(new BigInteger("0"));` for example.

Is there a way to get `BigInteger` working with Realm? There is a possibility for these values to be over the `Long` limit regularly which is why I am using `BigInteger` instead.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion would be:

- Use `String` or `byte[]` as the realm representation of the big integers, and convert between these types and `BigInteger` on the fly.
- If you want to cache a `BigInteger` object in your `RealmObject`, then use the `@Ignore` annotation to tell the Realm infrastructure not to try to pass it.

Something like this:

```
public class Bonus extends RealmObject {
   byte[] thebonus;

   @Ignore
   BigInteger bonus;

   public BigInteger getBonus() {
       if (bonus == null) {
           bonus = new BigInteger(thebonus);
       } 
       return bonus;
   }

   public void setBonus(BigInteger newBonus) {
       bonus = newBonus;
       thebonus = BigInteger.toByteArray();
   }
}
```

Using `byte[]` will be more efficient than `String` because the conversions will be faster ... for big enough integers.  (Text <-> binary conversion between base 10 and base 2^N will entail long multiplications and divisions.)

<sup>Disclaimer: this is just based on reading the [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#models). I've never used Realm.</sup>

Comment: Is that simply a matter of converting the `BigInteger` to `String`, passing it to the `setBonus()` method for example (after refactoring method and class to use `String` instead of `BigInteger`), saving that to Realm, then having `getBonus()` convert the `String` to `BigInteger` and return it? Or is there something I am missing? Thanks

Comment: Yes ... and the crucial `@Ignore` annotation ... if you cache the `BigInteger` in the `Bonus` object.